# Cannot access the link from my controller in jhipster app

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, spring-security, jhipster

I'm working with jhipster and created a test controller to see if my app is working correctly

You can see my controller below:

```
@RestController
@Configuration
public class TestController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @GetMapping("/test/github")
    public String testEndpoint() {
        log.info("Test endpoint called");
        return "Test endpoint response";
    }
}
```

and in my SecurityConfiguration file I included the line below:
`.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/test/github")).permitAll()`

and when I visit http://localhost:8080/test/github I get instantly redicricted to http://localhost:8080/not-found page

Not sure what I'm missing!!

Comment: you can start out by removing `@Configuration` thats not needed

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new condition to your project's `SpaWebFilter`. Here's [the one](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/_package_/web/filter/SpaWebFilter_imperative.java.ejs) that ships with JHipster.